# Uglify minification of if statment mismatch

Tags: javascript, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a JavaScript code as

```
if(msg.Url!==undefined && (msg.Url!==null || msg.Url!==''))
```

when i use `Uglify` to minify the same , it converts to

```
void 0 === msg.Url || null  === msg.Url && "" === msg.Url
```

isn't it wrong placement of `&&` and `||`

Comment: Notice it changed `!==` to `===` as well, so it's kind of inverted the whole thing. Which might still make sense depending on how it then applied it. What happened to the `if` keyword? Also, this part: `(msg.Url!==null || msg.Url!=='')` of your original condition will always be `true`.

Comment: The minified code will always return `false` if the `msg.Url` is `null`
where as the normal code will return `true`

Comment: Yes. Because `null  === msg.Url && "" === msg.Url` can never be `true`, just as your original `(msg.Url!==null || msg.Url!=='')` can never be `false`. So your source code had a logic problem to begin with. But again, whether the minification process got it wrong depends on how it actually applied the new version.

Comment: i guess best to use `if(!!msg.Url)` instead of the code i wrote

Answer (score 0):

i think after minifying the js the condition could be like this:

```
void 0!==msg.Url&&(null!==msg.Url||""!==msg.Url);
```

with if it would be:

```
if(void 0!==msg.Url&&(null!==msg.Url||""!==msg.Url))
```